# Do helper files that I import, also need import statements?

Tags: python, helper, python-module

I have a helper file which contains a function for plotting.

I also have my main notebook code, which uses the imports `sns` for seaborn, and `plt` for pyplot.

The helper file itself doesn't have an `import` statement to import these modules. In the notebook I am using it in, however, there are the following statements:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I import my helper file with the following line: `from helpers.plotter import plots`

And when I call the function I get the following error: `NameError: name 'plt' is not defined`

Do I need to have those import statements in the helper file? Is it not enough to have them in the notebook?

Comment: _"Do I need to have those import statements in the helper file"_: evidently, yes.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi are you making fun of me?! =P

Comment: No! You answered your own question, I was just pointing it out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `import` statement does two things:

1. If necessary, it evaluates the contents of a `.py` file to define the module.
2. It introduces a global variable in the current module to refer to the imported module.

#1 may not happen, if, for example, the same module has already been imported. It's #2 that *always* happens, and the failure to do so that leads to the error your see.

So yes, you need the `import` statement in your module.

Answer (score 1):

To add to [chepner's answer](/a/64249538/843953), the module is defined only once, to a single location in memory. When you add the import statement in the helper module, python only creates a variable in the helper module to point to the already-imported module in memory. This is clearly seen from the following experiment:

**File argparsetest.py**

```
import argparse

print("test:", hex(id(argparse)))
```

**File argparsemain.py**

```
import argparsetest

import argparse

print("main:", hex(id(argparse)))
```

On running `python argparsemain.py`, we get:

```
test: 0x23c04b59048
main: 0x23c04b59048
```

It wouldn't make a difference if you were to `import argparse` in `main.py` *before* importing `test.py`,

```
main: 0x130fc432f48
test: 0x130fc432f48
```